# cannot compile python.h windows

Tags: python, windows, numpy, pip

When I try to install numpy using `pip install numpy` the installation fails and I get the error message

> SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

Every thread I have found about this issue only has solutions for Linux so I was wondering if anyone had a fix for Windows, thanks!

Comment: Maybe you just want to install [a precompiled version of numpy](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)?

Comment: are you using python version 2 or 3? for version 3 you need to use pip3 instead.

Comment: I am using python 3 but using pip3 install numpy yields the same result